# unreachable statement after using .getActivity( ) in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment

I want to use .getSystemService in a Fragment. When i use .getActivity() to get the context of my activity, Android Studio tells me in the same line that this is a "unreachable statement".

When there is a line above the line where i use "getActivity()", it will show that this line on top is unreachable.

Why and how to fix this?

```
public class NewNodeFragment extends Fragment {

//GPS SIGNAL
double pLat;
double pLong;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newnode_layout, container,false);

    //GPS SIGNAL
    LocationManager gpsmanager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location lastLocation = gpsmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (lastLocation != null) {
        pLat = lastLocation.getLatitude();
        pLong = lastLocation.getLongitude();
    }

    LocationListener gpslistener = new mylocationListener();
    gpsmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpslistener);
}
```

Comment: Your problem: `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newnode_layout, container,false);`. DO NOT copy code from the internet. Please understand what it does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a return statement as the first line in your method, right above the line that has your comment //GPS SIGNAL...

Anything after a return statement is of course unreachable code.

Comment: I'm so dumb and blind. Thanks for your fast answer!

Comment: No problem!  I feel dumb and blind on a daily basis, so you're not alone.

Answer (score 6):

You would have to put all your code before the return statement.

```
public class NewNodeFragment extends Fragment {

//GPS SIGNAL
double pLat;
double pLong;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    //GPS SIGNAL
    LocationManager gpsmanager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location lastLocation = gpsmanager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (lastLocation != null) {
        pLat = lastLocation.getLatitude();
        pLong = lastLocation.getLongitude();
    }

    LocationListener gpslistener = new mylocationListener();
    gpsmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpslistener);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.newnode_layout, container,false);
}
```